# In Firebase we want to send data only to GTM and not to the GA. Android and IOS

Tags: android, ios, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

I have 3 questions regarding Firebase and GA integration with mobile app(both iOS and Android)

1. If we integrate Firebase and GTM with mobile applications without GA, Does it store any information in local storage(i.e moblie application local storage)?
2. if we integrate Firebase and GTM with mobile application with GA , with this relationship does it store any information in local storage (i.e Like how GA is storing ClientId )
3. we have a case in which we send data through the firebase, in this we want to send data only to GTM and not to the GA, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it will. GTM may store things that would indicate the build
   version of the container. Firebase would store more. Things like
   user ids, whether this is a first open or not and probably about ten
   more dimensions of similar value.
2. Yes.
3. No. GTM is not a destination for data. You don't send data to GTM.
   GTM doesn't have an endpoint to receive data. Instead, it's a bunch
   of logic that can route the data right from your front-end. However,
   GTM for mobile is severely limited in functionality, so we tend to
   only use it for simplest pixels implementation, and that still
   requires dev intervention.